# Capture-output, access to stdout files

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I create a simple workflow by Hue interface. In the shell action I check option Capture-stdout. And my question is: where I can find the file with stdout (to see it by command line) or how I can access to stdout of this workflow?

Comment: Maybe someone knows, how can I save output information from capture-output using wf:actionData EL function? Some examples, please?

Answer (score -1):

From the Shell action docs you need to use the EL function String action:output(String node, String key):
http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html

> If the capture-output element is present, it indicates Oozie to
>   capture output of the STDOUT of the shell command execution. The Shell
>   command output must be in Java Properties file format and it must not
>   exceed 2KB. From within the workflow definition, the output of an
>   Shell action node is accessible via the String action:output(String
>   node, String key) function (Refer to section '4.2.6 Action EL
>   Functions').

Comment: Thanks for answer. Could You show some example, how to use this function? Is this function working only with Java actions in Oozie? How can I use this function to put stdout file to specified catalog in my local directory?